# Change the mask of Kendo MaskedTextBox in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I am using the below code to set up the Kendo MaskedTextBox

```
<input type="text" kendo-masked-text-box k-mask="contact.Mask"  ng-model="contact.PhoneNumber" />
```

In my angular Mask is initially set to empty and then I change it in a function.
Example :

```
$scope.contact.Mask = '';
$scope.changeMask = function(){
    $scope.contact.Mask = '(999) 000-0000';
}
```

Calling this function does change the value of $scope.contact.Mask but the actual textbox does not reflect the change.

Please let me know in case any other information is requried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `k-rebind="contact.Mask"`. This should solve your problem.